# saving arguments with ArgumentParser in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

i obtain different arguments from command lines:

```
def get_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='neural network project')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=150)
    parser.add_argument('--decay_epoch', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=.0002)
    parser.add_argument('--load_height', type=int, default=286)
    parser.add_argument('--load_width', type=int, default=286)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

I would like to save all the argument obtained from get_args in a dictionary (to save then in a file .json or in a .txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args` returns an `argparse.Namespace` object, which is trivial to turn into a dict. Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace):

> This class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a
> readable string representation. If you prefer to have dict-like view
> of the attributes, you can use the standard Python idiom, vars():

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary and add them by parser keyword.

```
neural_dict = {}
neural_dict['EPOCHS'] = args.epochs
neural_dict['DECAY_EPOCH'] = args.decay_epoch
.
.
.
```

To add to dictionary using a for loop:

```
neural_dict = {}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='neural network project')
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=150)
parser.add_argument('--decay_epoch', type=int, default=100)
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=.0002)
parser.add_argument('--load_height', type=int, default=286)
parser.add_argument('--load_width', type=int, default=286)
args = parser.parse_args()

#chepner is right...use his method instead
neural_dict = vars(args)
```

Comment: and is possibile do it with a cycle for?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how. As Paul says, you have to use vars() to use the attributes of the argument.

Comment: Your loop is basically just `neural_dict = var(args)` (or `neural_dict.update(var(args))`)

Comment: Thanks @chepner! Great catch!